# How use multitype Model in one layout (with partial)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model, partial

I have page where I use model which can have different types (depending by action and controller). My **problem** starts when I want to use partial which take parameter from Model like:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Components/SubMenu.cshtml", MyProject.Web.MenuHelper.GetSubMenu(Model.field1))
```

but, if I not declare type of model I have an error like `Partial can not use dynamic values`. So I have idea to solve it with:

```
@if (Model.GetType() == typeof(ContentPage))
{
    @model ContentPage
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Components/SubMenu.cshtml", MyProject.Web.MenuHelper.GetSubMenu(Model.field1))
}
else if (Model.GetType() == typeof(Data.Models.Directory))
{
    @model Directories
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Components/SubMenu.cshtml", MyProject.Web.MenuHelper.GetSubMenu(Model.field2))
}
```

But then I have error like: `ContentPage.field2 no exist`.

Do you have any ideas how can I solve it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: when ever you find yourself testing the type of an object (especially for control flow) think "Might I have a design issue?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a good idea to strongly type a view or a partial view with different models based upon conditions. If you still want to use different kind of models in a view/partial view then you have to go for `ViewData`/`ViewBag` approach.

The other option is you can go for generic view models see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388960/generic-view-models).